# 3D building data is stored in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, 3d-model

I was wondering in what way (data format, infrastructure) 3D building data is stored in [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/@52.07990347,4.32041704,69.85325981a,619.36363067d,35y,95.62966958h,56.52497261t,-0r). I am very impressed by the quality and performance. Are the vertices of the mesh stored in spatial coordinates or some other format?

For example: OBJ, Collada, FBX, OSGB etc.

In addition, is there an [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/is) compliant alternative for Open Source applications?

[image]

Comment: Certainly not familiar with specifics for underpinnings of Google Earth 3d, but [CityGML](https://www.citygml.org/) is an OGC compliant format. I *think* the opensource [Cesium.JS library](https://cesiumjs.org/) can use CityGML).

ESRI Multipatch is another framework I often see, though it might not be OGC compliant... but it's a format that QGIS readily imports for 3d visualization.

(If you're curious to work with some of these data types, NYC 3d building data are posted [here](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/doitt/initiatives/3d-building.page)